# R targets with H2O

Tags: r, h2o, targets-r-package

I use [`targets`](https://github.com/ropensci/targets) as a pipelining tool for an ML project with [`H2O`](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/index.html).
The main uniqueness of using H2O here is that it creates a new "cluster" (basically a new local process/server which communicates via Rest APIs as far as I understand).

The issue I am having is two-fold.

1. How can I stop/operate the cluster within the targets framework in a smart way
2. How can I save & load the data/models within the targets framework

### MWE

A minimum working example I came up with looks like this (being the `_targets.R` file):

```r
library(targets)
library(h2o)

# start h20 cluster once _targets.R gets evaluated
h2o.init(nthreads = 2, max_mem_size = "2G", port = 54322, name = "TESTCLUSTER")

create_dataset_h2o <- function() {
  # connect to the h2o cluster
  h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54322, name = "TESTCLUSTER", startH2O = FALSE)
  # convert the data to h2o dataframe
  as.h2o(iris)
}
train_model <- function(hex_data) {
  # connect to the h2o cluster
  h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54322, name = "TESTCLUSTER", startH2O = FALSE)

  h2o.randomForest(x = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"),
                   y = c("Species"),
                   training_frame = hex_data,
                   model_id = "our.rf",
                   seed = 1234)
}
predict_model <- function(model, hex_data) {
  # connect to the h2o cluster
  h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54322, name = "TESTCLUSTER", startH2O = FALSE)
  h2o.predict(model, newdata = hex_data)
}

list(
  tar_target(data, create_dataset_h2o()),
  tar_target(model, train_model(data), format = "qs"),
  tar_target(predict, predict_model(model, data), format = "qs")
)
```

This kinda works but faces the two issues I was outlying above and below...

### Ad 1 - stopping the cluster

Usually I would out a `h2o::h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE)` at the end of my script, but this does not work in this case.
Alternatively, I came up with a new target that is always run.

```r
# in _targets.R in the final list
  tar_target(END, h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE), cue = tar_cue(mode = "always"))
```

This works when I run `tar_make()` but not when I use `tar_visnetwork()`.

Another option is to use.

```r
# after the h2o.init(...) call inside _targets.R
on.exit(h2o.shutdown(prompt = FALSE), add = TRUE)
```

Another alternative that I came up with is to handle the server outside of targets and only connect to it. But I feel that this might break the targets workflow...

Do you have any other idea how to handle this?

### Ad 2 - saving the dataset and model

The code in the MWE does not save the data for the targets `model` and `predict` in the correct format (`format = "qs"`). Sometimes (I think when the cluster gets restarted or so), the data gets "invalidated" and h2o throws an error. The data in h2o format in the R session is a pointer to the h2o dataframe (see also [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/frame.html)).

For keras, which similarly stores the models outside of R, there is the option [`format = "keras"`](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/practices.html), which calls `keras::save_model_hdf5()` behind the scenes. Similarly, H2O would require `h2o::h2o.exportFile()` and `h2o::h2o.importFile()` for the dataset and `h2o::h2o.saveModel()` and `h2o::h2o.loadModel()` for models (see also [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html)).

Is there a way to create additional formats for `tar_targets` or do I need to write the data to file, and return the file? The downside to this is that this file is outside of the `_targets` folder system, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ad 1

I would recommend handling the H2O cluster outside the pipeline in a separate script. That way, `tar_visnetwork()` would not start or stop the cluster, and you could more cleanly separate the software engineering from the data analysis.

```
# run_pipeline.R
start_h2o_cluster(port = ...)
on.exit(stop_h2o_cluster(port = ...))
targets::tar_make_clustermq(workers = 4)
```

## Ad 2

It sounds like H2O objects are [not exportable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html). Currently, you would need to save those files manually, identify the paths, and write `format = "file"` in `tar_target()`. I am willing to consider H20-based formats. Are all objects in some way covered by `h2o.exportFile()`, `h2o.importFile()`, `h2o::h2o.saveModel()`, and `h2o::h2o.loadModel()`, or are there more kinds of objects with different serialization functions? And does `h2o` have utilities to perform this (un)serialization in memory like `serialize_model()`/`unserialize_model()` in `keras`?

Comment: ad1 makes totally sense to me! Ill check about serialization of models in h2o. Do you want me to open an issue/feature request on github?

Comment: Thanks, let's discuss at https://github.com/ropensci/targets/issues/464.

Comment: Moved to a discussion: https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/466